# Erro na hora de mostrar os resultados - URI 1566

Tags: c

Fiz como pedido no enunciado do [problema 1566 do URI](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1566), só que está dando erro de apresentação, e não sei como corrigir.

Segue o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ordena(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int teste, num;
  scanf("%d", &teste);
  for(int i = 0; i < teste; i++)
  {
     scanf("%d", &num);
     int vetor[num];
     for(int j = 0; j < num; j++)
     {
        scanf("%d", &vetor[j]);
     }
     qsort(vetor, num, sizeof(int), ordena);
     for(int j = 0; j < num; j++)
     {
        printf("%d ", vetor[j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
  return 0;
}

int ordena(const void *a, const void *b)
{

   if(*(int*)a == *(int*)b)
    return 0;
   else if(*(int*)a < * (int*)b)
    return -1;
   else
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o problema está aqui:

```
       printf("%d ", vetor[j]);
```

Esse espaço no final vai bagunçar a verificação automática da saída do código. Tente fazer assim:

```
       if (z != 0) printf(" ");
       printf("%d", vetor[j]);
```

Com isso, você passa a ter os espaços antes do número, apenas se não for o primeiro, o que deve corrigir esse problema.

Talvez o `printf("\n");` pode dar um problema semelhante também. A solução também seria colocar um `if` nisso.

Comment: Olha fiz o que você mandou, só que acho por causa desse if, o tempo de estorou

Comment: @rafaelmarques Ah, se o tempo estourou foi outra coisa: O quicksort tem desempenho **O(n log n)** na MÉDIA. Mas, no pior caso, o quicksort é **O(n²)**. O teste do URI deve ter colocado algumas entradas que geram o pior caso. A solução para isso é usar um outro algoritmo de ordenação, tal como o mergesort, que é sempre **O(n log n)** mesmo no pior caso.

Comment: Tem outra maneira menos elegante de por o espaço condicionalmente, porém sem precisar gerar _branches_ de execução. Hipoteticamente o compilador poderia detectar isso pra você também. É o caso de extrair o primeiro elemento e nos conseguintes imprimir com o espaço antes do número. Isso mantém a mesma quantidade de chamadas a `printf` praticamente e evita execução condicional

Comment: Tipo, `if (num > 0) { printf("%d", vetor[0]); for (int j = 1;...) { printf(" %d", vetor[j]); }`

Comment: Com ajuda do @Jefferson Quesado, o código passou, obrigado victor e Jefferson Quesado pela ajuda